# (Normality) assumptions of logistic multilevel model (glmmTMB)

Tags: logistic, multilevel-analysis, normality-assumption, assumptions, glmmtmb

I have a dataset with patient data in a psychiatric hospital. Some patients had more than one stay, so the observations are not completely independent. I therefore used a multilevel model (in R with glmmTMB) with the patient cases als level 1 and the patients as level 2. The model contains random intercepts for patients. I used family = binomial because of the binary outcome variable.

When trying to check for the assumptions of such a model I read that non-normality of random effects (random intercepts in my case) could be problematic. The histogram of my random intercepts definitely showed non-normality. I tried log-transforming the random intercepts and adding those as a predictor in the model. The fixed effects changed a bit and the diagnostics made with DHARMa package looked better after. Also the AIC decreased. But I'm not sure if this an validated approach. Does someone have an opinion on that?

In addition, even after a lot of research, I am not completely sure what assumptions are relevant for a logistic multilevel model and how to test them (I found different information in different sources).
Thanks for any help.